# Title Tag is not displaying German accent characters correctly

Tags: multilingual

I am working with Sitecore SXA. In title tag German, French or any special characters are not working in page source. The title is working fine in browser title but not in  tag in page source.

I have tried the following tags also:

```
 - <meta charset="UTF-8">
 - <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 - <html lang="en, de, fr">
```

None of them is working. Please have a look at the attached screenshots.
[image]
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `&#246;` is encoded version of `ö`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is the encoded form of ö

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: Can you try <title>@Html.Raw("Your Content")</title>

Answer (score 6):

There is no problem here - this is how HTML works.

Your output is being encoded in a form that stands the greatest chance of being interpreted correctly by the visitor to the site, regardless of OS, culture settings and any other factors.

The German letter `ö` is code #246 in the [ISO-8859-1 (ISO Latin 1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) character set; which is what is reflected in your View Source as well. And as you can see from your own screenshot, your machine interprets this character correctly and shows you `ö`.

[image]